# Storing Statistics in Java Calculator

Tags: java

Having difficulty storing the following statistics to be printed when the program terminates. I have been able to store the total number of valid and invalid expressions however I am having difficulty with the following:

- The highest overall result value.
- The lowest overall result value.
- The aggregate of all result values, i.e. all results added together.
- The average result value

Any guidance for any of the above would be much appreciated.

```
    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in); // Creating new scanner to take user choice input
    int validExpressions = 0;
    int invalidExpressions = 0;
    int lowestval = 0;
    int highestval;
    while (true) {

        System.out.println("Enter K to enter a postfix expression or F to open a text file:"); // requesting user input

        String choice = input.nextLine(); // Taking user input from keyboard, either K for manual entry or F for file input

        float answer; // Variable used to store answers.


         if ("F".equals(choice)) {
            System.out.println("Please enter the name of a .txt file:"); // user prompted to enter the name of the text file

            String file = input.nextLine(); // File name will be stored in a String (file) to be used later
            File txtfile = new File(file); 
            Scanner reader = new Scanner(txtfile); // Creating a new scanner which reads the text file

            while (reader.hasNextLine()) { // The new scanner (reader) reads each line of the text file

                String expression = reader.nextLine(); // Each line is stored in a String called Expression
                String[] parts = expression.split(" "); // The string is split into three parts; two numbers and an operator

                String part1 = parts[0];
                String part2 = parts[1];
                String part3 = parts[2];

                float number1 = Float.parseFloat(part1); // Parts one and two are both converted from a String to a Float
                float number2 = Float.parseFloat(part2); 

                // Program processes the operator and applies it to Float number1 and Float number2 before outputting the 
                // expression and the correct answer
                if ("+".equals(part3)) {
                    answer = number1 + number2;
                    System.out.println(part1 + " " + "+" + " " + part2 + " " + "=" + " " + answer);
                    validExpressions++;
                } else if ("-".equals(part3)) {
                    answer = number1 - number2;
                    System.out.println(part1 + " " + "-" + " " + part2 + " " + "=" + " " + answer);
                    validExpressions++;
                } else if ("*".equals(part3)) {
                    answer = number1 * number2;
                    System.out.println(part1 + " " + "*" + " " + part2 + " " + "=" + " " + answer);
                    validExpressions++;
                } else if ("/".equals(part3)) {
                    answer = number1 / number2;
                    System.out.println(part1 + " " + "/" + " " + part2 + " " + "=" + " " + answer);
                    validExpressions++;
                }

            }

        } else if ("K".equals(choice)) // If the user enters K input will be taken from the keyboard

            System.out.println("Please enter a post-fix expression:"); // User is prompted to enter a post fix expression

        Scanner expression = new Scanner(System.in); // Creating a new Scanner called Expression to read user input
        String exp = expression.nextLine(); // The user's input is stored in a string
        String[] elements = exp.split(" "); // Expression is split into three elements, two numbers and an operator

        String element1 = elements[0];
        String element2 = elements[1];
        String element3 = elements[2];

        float num1 = Float.parseFloat(element1); // Element1 and element2 are converted to Floats and named num1 and num2
        float num2 = Float.parseFloat(element2);


        // Program processes the operator and applies it to Float num1 and Float num2 before outputting the 
        // expression and the correct answer 
        if ("+".equals(element3)) {
            answer = num1 + num2;
            System.out.println(element1 + " " + "+" + " " + element2 + " " + "=" + " " + answer);
            validExpressions++;
        } else if ("-".equals(element3)) {
            answer = num1 - num2;
            System.out.println(element1 + " " + "-" + " " + element2 + " " + "=" + " " + answer);
            validExpressions++;
        } else if ("*".equals(element3)) {
            answer = num1 * num2;
            System.out.println(element1 + " " + "*" + " " + element2 + " " + "=" + " " + answer);
            validExpressions++;
        } else if ("/".equals(element3)) {
            answer = num1 / num2;
            System.out.println(element1 + " " + "/" + " " + element2 + " " + "=" + " " + answer);
            validExpressions++;

            if (choice.isEmpty()) { // If the user does not enter K or F the program will exit
                System.out.println("Evaluations Complete");
                System.out.println("-------------------------");
                System.out.println("Valid expressions: " + validExpressions);
                System.out.println("Invalid expressions: " + invalidExpressions);
                System.exit(0); 
            }
        }
      }                          
   }
 }
```

Comment: And what is your question?

Comment: Apologies. How would I go about this to put it in its most simplest form.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Please [edit](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/34135803/edit) your post to include your question. Also, please highlight what you have issues with (we don't want to sift through hundred lines of code). Please see [how to ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [minimal example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Answer (score 0):

I have changed something wrong on logic and syntax，but I have not debuged it ,you may have a try.

```
Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in); // Creating new scanner to take user   choice input
int validExpressions = 0;
int invalidExpressions = 0;
float lowestval = 0;
float highestval =0 ;
float total=0;
while (true) {

    System.out.println("Enter K to enter a postfix expression or F to open a text file:"); // requesting user input

    String choice = input.nextLine(); // Taking user input from keyboard, either K for manual entry or F for file input

    float answer; // Variable used to store answers.


     if ("F".equals(choice)) {
        System.out.println("Please enter the name of a .txt file:"); // user prompted to enter the name of the text file

        String file = input.nextLine(); // File name will be stored in a String (file) to be used later
        File txtfile = new File(file); 
        Scanner reader = new Scanner(txtfile); // Creating a new scanner which reads the text file

        while (reader.hasNextLine()) { // The new scanner (reader) reads each line of the text file

            String expression = reader.nextLine(); // Each line is stored in a String called Expression
            String[] parts = expression.split(" "); // The string is split into three parts; two numbers and an operator

            String part1 = parts[0];
            String part2 = parts[1];
            String part3 = parts[2];

            float number1 = Float.parseFloat(part1); // Parts one and two are both converted from a String to a Float
            float number2 = Float.parseFloat(part2); 

            // Program processes the operator and applies it to Float number1 and Float number2 before outputting the 
            // expression and the correct answer
            if ("+".equals(part3)) {
                answer = number1 + number2;
                System.out.println(part1 + " " + "+" + " " + part2 + " " + "=" + " " + answer);
                validExpressions++;
            } else if ("-".equals(part3)) {
                answer = number1 - number2;
                System.out.println(part1 + " " + "-" + " " + part2 + " " + "=" + " " + answer);
                validExpressions++;
            } else if ("*".equals(part3)) {
                answer = number1 * number2;
                System.out.println(part1 + " " + "*" + " " + part2 + " " + "=" + " " + answer);
                validExpressions++;
            } else if ("/".equals(part3)) {
                answer = number1 / number2;
                System.out.println(part1 + " " + "/" + " " + part2 + " " + "=" + " " + answer);
                validExpressions++;
            } else{
                invalidExcepressions++;
                continue;
            }
            highestval=(highestval>=answer)?highestval:answer;
            lowestval=(lowestval<=answer)?lowestval:answer;
            total+=answer;
        }

    } else if ("K".equals(choice)){ // If the user enters K input will be taken from the keyboard

        System.out.println("Please enter a post-fix expression:"); // User is prompted to enter a post fix expression

    Scanner expression = new Scanner(System.in); // Creating a new Scanner called Expression to read user input
    String exp = expression.nextLine(); // The user's input is stored in a string
    String[] elements = exp.split(" "); // Expression is split into three elements, two numbers and an operator

    String element1 = elements[0];
    String element2 = elements[1];
    String element3 = elements[2];

    float num1 = Float.parseFloat(element1); // Element1 and element2 are converted to Floats and named num1 and num2
    float num2 = Float.parseFloat(element2);


    // Program processes the operator and applies it to Float num1 and Float num2 before outputting the 
    // expression and the correct answer 
    if ("+".equals(element3)) {
        answer = num1 + num2;
        System.out.println(element1 + " " + "+" + " " + element2 + " " + "=" + " " + answer);
        validExpressions++;          
    } else if ("-".equals(element3)) {
        answer = num1 - num2;
        System.out.println(element1 + " " + "-" + " " + element2 + " " + "=" + " " + answer);
        validExpressions++;
    } else if ("*".equals(element3)) {
        answer = num1 * num2;
        System.out.println(element1 + " " + "*" + " " + element2 + " " + "=" + " " + answer);
        validExpressions++;
    } else if ("/".equals(element3)) {
        answer = num1 / num2;
        System.out.println(element1 + " " + "/" + " " + element2 + " " + "=" + " " + answer);
        validExpressions++;
    }else{
        invalidExceotions++;
        continue;
    }
    highestval=(highestval>=answer)?highestval:answer;
    lowestval=(lowestval<=answer)?lowestval:answer;
    total+=answer;
}else if (choice.isEmpty()) { // If the user does not enter K or F the program will exit
            System.out.println("Evaluations Complete");
            System.out.println("-------------------------");
            System.out.println("Valid expressions: " + validExpressions);
            System.out.println("Invalid expressions: " + invalidExpressions);
            System.out.println("Total :"+total);
            System.out.println("Average :"+total/validExceptions);
            System.exit(0); 
        }
```

}

Comment: Please don't just post code - explain what it is that you have changed.

Comment: Thank you very much. Could you just briefly explain how this works: highestval=(highestval>=answer)?highestval:answer;
    lowestval=(lowestval<=answer)?lowestval:answer;
    total+=answer;